# Scala - Pattern Match in Method Arguments?

Tags: scala

How do I break apart a case class in the arguments of a method?

```
scala> case class f(a:Int,b:Int)

defined class f

scala> def z((a,b):f) = a + b
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but '(' found.
def z((a,b):f) = a + b
      ^
```

Is this the only way to get what I want?

```
def z(r:f) = r match {case f(a,b)=>a+b}
```

Or is there a more idiomatic way?

Comment: Just `def z(r:f) = r.a + r.b`

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHH In Haskell you'd need lens for that. OK that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your case class is as simple as this, you can use what @XavierGuihot suggested in the comments. Otherwise, you need pattern matching. However, there are two way to use it: either as you did, using `match` keyword, or with a partial function syntax:

```
val z: f => Int = {
  case f(a, b) => a + b
}
```